# Parse command line arguments & response files

Tags: c++

I need to parse command line arguments, and response files with comments.

Can any body suggest me some libraries, like [getoptpp](http://code.google.com/p/getoptpp/), bit this one not support parse response files.

And please do not suggest [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/program_options) (because boost does not provide direct support for response files, and also I didn`t use it in my project)

If some body don`t know what `response file` is
`Response file - is just a configuration file which uses the same syntax as the command line`

Thanks!

**Upd**: response file can have comments
**Upd2**: snippet of a "response file"

```
# verbose
-v
--port 80 # port
```

And arguments of command line

```
foo --port 80 -v
or
foo -p 80 -v
```

Comment: Why not use getoptpp (or other arg parsing lib) but just feed the "response files" into it as well?

Comment: doh I was about to suggest boost::program_options

Comment: If a response file is identical to command line, then the Boost Program_Options should indeed be ok.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, it is not identical to command line, it can have comments

Comment: @therefromhere, because if there is such library, and it easy to learn , than I think that better to use it, then write own

Comment: @azat: Then please make this sort of thing clear in your question.  How can we possibly help if we don't know your constraints?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, edit question

Comment: @azat: It would help if you actually include an example snippet of a "response file" in your question.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, include snipplet

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling turned up one answer.  The LLVM compiler tool kit at http://llvm.org/ includes a command line library that claims to handle response files.  (See http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html.)  Perhaps you can pull that out of the toolkit and use it?

Other than that, the solution seems to be reading the file, turning it into `argv` style arguments and passing it to one of the usual parsers.